# can't ssh and open aws ubuntu server

Tags: ssh, apache-http-server, amazon-web-services

I am having ubuntu 14.04 server on aws and I tried following commands for some reasons,

```
sudo ufw disable
sudo ufw enable
```

After this command, I can't ssh to server and also can't open website which I made on that server. Means neither 22 port nor 80 port are working. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you need to enable the connections thru that ports, for example `sudo ufw allow ssh` is a short version of `sudo ufw allow 22/tcp`, you can read more here:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-an-ubuntu-and-debian-cloud-server

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but now I can't ssh so how could I'll be able to command to server.

Comment: the problem is that you enabled the firewall to avoid connections so you need to check the control panel of your server and see if there is another way to get in.

Comment: Hi @Genaro Morales, can you explain in detail, because I am very new to aws.

Comment: Your ubuntu server is an instance on AWS, you need to log in into your amazon account on a web browser and go to the instances menu, there you'll see your server, I don't know if there is another way you can get in or if there is an option to disable the firewall from there.